# Two Dimensional ArrayList with different types

Tags: java

Lets say I wanted to create an `ArrayList` like the following:

```
[
    [500000, 999999, 900000, "D\u0305", "C\u0305M\u0305"]
    [100000, 499999, 400000, "C\u0305", "C\u0305D\u0305"]
    [50000, 99999, 90000, "L\u0305", "X\u0305C\u0305"]
    [10000, 49999, 40000, "X\u0305", "X\u0305L\u0305"]
    [5000, 9999, 9000, "V\u0305", "MX\u0305"]
    [1000, 4999, 4000, "M", "MV\u0305"]
    [500, 999, 900, "D", "CM"]
    [100, 499, 400, "C", "CD"]
    [50, 99, 90, "L", "XC"]
    [10, 49, 40, "X", "XL"]
]
```

Does anyone know the best route to implement something like this with java?

Comment: Create a class which contains the fields of your array. Then your 2D array becomes an `Array<MyClass>`.

Comment: To have numbers and strings as possible elements you would have to define the elements as `Object`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've searched this in 5 different ways and the 5th way of searching I found it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099463/two-dimensional-array-with-different-types

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly unclear what you're asking. In Java we don't actually have 2D arrays. Instead we have arrays of arrays. Similarly there is just 1D `ArrayList` which can contain different `ArrayList`s.

Another thing is the type stored. I would suggest writing your own class which would store the number Roman or Arabic.

```
public class RomanOrArabic {
    private Long arabic;
    private String roman;

    public boolean isArabic(){
        return arabic != null;
    }
    //add getters, smart setters, validators for String being Roman etc.
}
```

Then declare your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<RomanOrArabic>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw there was some confusion so I thought I would post the solution here.

```
    // The solution
    Object RomanNumeralValues[][] = {
            {500000, 999999, 900000, "D\u0305", "C\u0305M\u0305"},
            {100000, 499999, 400000, "C\u0305", "C\u0305D\u0305"},
            {50000, 99999, 90000, "L\u0305", "X\u0305C\u0305"},
            {10000, 49999, 40000, "X\u0305", "X\u0305L\u0305"},
            {5000, 9999, 9000, "V\u0305", "MX\u0305"},
            {1000, 4999, 4000, "M", "MV\u0305"},
            {500, 999, 900, "D", "CM"},
            {100, 499, 400, "C", "CD"},
            {50, 99, 90, "L", "XC"},
            {10, 49, 40, "X", "XL"}
    };

    // Where the solution gets used
    String romanNumeral = "";
    for (Object rmRange[]: RomanNumeralValues) {
        romanNumeral += extractRomanNumeralsBelowOneMillion(
                (int)rmRange[0],
                (int)rmRange[1],
                (int)rmRange[2],
                rmRange[3].toString(),
                rmRange[4].toString()
        );
    }
```

I'm not comfortable with type casting just to pull the value out of an object array, but I guess it works. I'll leave the question open in case anyone has better solutions.

Comment: It's a bad idea. Why to use casting and catch `CastException` when you can use your own class. Have a look at my answer.